How to compute univ3 market depth
I have the following elements for a Mint event, and same for a burn event
liquidity_amount, token0_amount, token1_amount, token0_decimals, token1_decimals, lower_tick, upper_tick.

How can I recreate the market depth from those elements please?
For instance:
event: Mint
liquidity: 8039644
token0_amount: -79992
token1_amount: -80000
token0_decimals: 6
token1_decimals: 6
lower_tick: -20000
upper_tick: 20000

event: Burn
liquidity: -45561083896
token0_amount: 455653364
token1_amount: 450573703
token0_decimals: 6
token1_decimals: 6
lower_tick: -20000
upper_tick: 20000

Any idea please?
